# How to change data between wide and long formats in R?

Tags: data-transformation, r

You can have data in wide format or in long format.
This is quite an important thing, as the useable methods are different, depending on the format.
I know you have to work with `melt()` and `cast()` from the reshape package, but there seems some things that I don't get.

Can someone give me a short overview how you do this?

Comment: Please provide the example of what you want to achieve. What exactly you do not get?

Comment: Here is [my blog post](http://vzemlys.wordpress.com/2010/01/06/time-series-data-aggregation-using-r-and-reshape/) with example of using `melt` and `cast`. There conversion from wide to long format is done at one stage. There really isn't anything more special.

Comment: Welcome to stats.  You might find it helps to include a small, reproducible dataset in your question to explain what you want.  Read http://www.sigmafield.org/2011/01/18/three-tips-for-posting-good-questions-to-r-help-and-stack-overflow for more.

Comment: See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) for many ways to do this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are several resources on Hadley Wickham's [website](http://had.co.nz/reshape/) for the package (now called `reshape2`), including a link to a [paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v21/i12) on the package in the Journal of Statistical Software.

Here is a brief example from the paper:

```
> require(reshape2)
Loading required package: reshape2
> data(smiths)
> smiths
     subject time age weight height
1 John Smith    1  33     90   1.87
2 Mary Smith    1  NA     NA   1.54
```

We note that the data are in the wide form. To go to the long form, we make the `smiths` data frame *molten*:

```
> melt(smiths)
Using subject as id variables
     subject variable value
1 John Smith     time  1.00
2 Mary Smith     time  1.00
3 John Smith      age 33.00
4 Mary Smith      age    NA
5 John Smith   weight 90.00
6 Mary Smith   weight    NA
7 John Smith   height  1.87
8 Mary Smith   height  1.54
```

Notice how `melt()` chose one of the variables as the id, but we can state explicitly which to use via argument `'id'`:

```
> melt(smiths, id = "subject")
     subject variable value
1 John Smith     time  1.00
2 Mary Smith     time  1.00
3 John Smith      age 33.00
4 Mary Smith      age    NA
5 John Smith   weight 90.00
6 Mary Smith   weight    NA
7 John Smith   height  1.87
8 Mary Smith   height  1.54
```

Here is another example from `?cast`:

```
#Air quality example
names(airquality) <- tolower(names(airquality))
aqm <- melt(airquality, id=c("month", "day"), na.rm=TRUE)
```

If we store the molten data frame, we can *cast* into other forms. In the new version of `reshape` (called `reshape2`) there are functions `acast()` and `dcast()` returning an array-like (array, matrix, vector) result or a data frame respectively. These functions also take an aggregating function (eg `mean()`) to provide summaries of data in molten form. For example, following on from the Air Quality example above, we can generate, in wide form, monthly mean values for the variables in the data set:

```
> dcast(aqm, month ~ variable, mean)
  month    ozone  solar.r      wind     temp
1     5 23.61538 181.2963 11.622581 65.54839
2     6 29.44444 190.1667 10.266667 79.10000
3     7 59.11538 216.4839  8.941935 83.90323
4     8 59.96154 171.8571  8.793548 83.96774
5     9 31.44828 167.4333 10.180000 76.90000
```

There are really only two main functions in `reshape2`: `melt()` and the `acast()` and `dcast()` pairing. Look at the examples in the help pages for these two functions, see Hadley's website (link above) and look at the paper I mentioned. That should get you started.

You might also look into Hadley's [`plyr` package](http://had.co.nz/plyr/) which does similar things to `reshape2` but is designed to do a whole lot more besides.

Comment: `dcast(aqm, month ~ variable)`, what would this do without the aggregating function?

Comment: @CravingSpirit it would return the number of observations for each variable. Read `?dcast` which would have told you this (see the details for argument `fun.aggregate`).

Answer (score 8):

- [Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/management/reshape.html) has simple example of using reshape package
- See also `?reshape` ([LINK](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/reshape.html)) for the Base R way of moving between wide and long format.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to use `melt` and `cast`.

Reshaping data can be done lots of ways.  In your particular example on your cite using `recast` with `aggregate` was redundant because `aggregate` does the task fine all on it's own.

```
aggregate(cbind(LPMVTUZ, LPMVTVC, LPMVTXC) ~ year, dtm, sum)
# or even briefer by first removing the columns you don't want to use
aggregate(. ~ year, dtm[,-2], sum)
```

I do like how, in your blog post, you explain what `melt` is doing.  Very few people understand that and once you see it then it gets easier to see how `cast` works and how you might write your own functions if you want.

Answer (score 2):

See [the reshape2 wiki](https://wiki.cmbi.ru.nl/index.php/Introductory-R-Course/reshape2). It surely provides more examples as you could expect.

Answer (score 2):

Just noticing there's no reference to the more efficient and extensive reshaping methods in `data.table` here, so I am posting without further comment the excellent answer by Zach/Arun on StackOverflow for a similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902087/proper-fastest-way-to-reshape-a-data-table/6913151#6913151

And in particular there's the wonderful vignette on the `data.table` GitHub page:

https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started